# "process.env.DATABASE_URL" is not populating in app deployed on Google Cloud Run

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-sql, google-cloud-run

Below NodeJS code works fine when I deploy to Heroku.

```
var pgp = require("pg-promise")(/*options*/);

function PostgresDBAdapter() {
  var db = pgp(
    process.env.DATABASE_URL ||
      "postgres://postgres:123456@localhost:5432/surveyjs"
  );

  function getObjectFromStorage(tableName, callback) {
    db.any("SELECT * FROM " + tableName).then(function (result) {
      var objects = {};
      (result || []).forEach(function (item) {
        objects[item.id] = item;
      });
      callback(objects);
    });
  }
```

But when I deploy to Google Cloud Run , "process.env.DATABASE_URL" is not populating. What environment variable I put or what url syntax i should follow?. I have already attached cloud sql instance to my app while deploying to cloud run.
Thanks.

Comment: Show the `gcloud run deploy` command that you are using. You set the value of `DATABASE_URL` during deploy using the `--set-env-vars` or `--update-env-vars` command line option.

Comment: How are you deploying your application?

Comment: See the documentation here: https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/postgres/connect-run#node.js

Comment: Thank you. All. I have rewritten the code using pg-promise for nodeJs. it works fine.

Comment: var pgp = require("pg-promise")(/*options*/);

const databaseConfig= {
  "host": '/cloudsql/<instance name>',
  "database": 'db1',
  "user": 'postgres',
  "password": 'password123',
   "port": 5432
};

function PostgresDBAdapter() {
  var db = pgp(databaseConfig);

Comment: Hello @Jazzusg can you please add your solution code as an answer. It might be helpful for other people who will face the same issue.

Answer (score 1):

I have rewritten code as below, it works fine.

var pgp = require("pg-promise")(/*options*/);
const databaseConfig= { "host": '/cloudsql/', "database": 'db1', "user": 'postgres', "password": 'password123', "port": 5432 };

function PostgresDBAdapter()
{ var db = pgp(databaseConfig);

Comment: If this works, it means that your connection string is incorrect, that's all. You just need to fix the syntax according to what you are expecting. When host name starts with `/` that's usually a socket, and not domain name. If that's the case, you need to sue socket syntax.